# Movement commands for Solo on GPS-denied manual modes

Tags: dronekit-python, 3dr

I am working on an indoor vision based navigation in a GPS denied environment, and I'm using a 3DR Solo. I want to be able to send movement commands to the Solo through the DroneKit API. Are these mavlink commands supported for modes other than GUIDED and AUTO, or is channel overriding my only option?

Comment: Amy I believe GUIDED and AUTO are your only options, what type of sensor are you planning on using?, there might be some more info on the ardupilot forums http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-optional-hardware.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to control it. If you want to control the position of the copter, you will need to make hardware modifications to the solo, because it does not have the right sensors to be able to hold position indoors. If you want to control the raw angle of the copter, the cleanest way to do this is to send a SET_ATTITUDE_TARGET message. The problem is that this is only supported in guided mode, and guided mode won't arm without gps (even though low-level control like SET_ATTITUDE_TARGET doesn't rely on GPS). Guided-NoGPS mode is currently on the todo list for ArduCopter, so comment on the issue [here](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot/issues/2790) to let the devs know that you are interested in this feature.